# Возможно ли в параметр функции указать не просто тип данных, а типы строк которую она может принимать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу, чтобы unit_format принимал такие значения = "B" | "BT" | "KB"....
Привык к TS, но может есть модуль под такую типизацию?

```
def file_size_calc(unit_format:str, size:int | float) -> int:
    units_information = {"B": 1, "BT": 8, "KB": 1024, "MB": 1024 ** 2, "GB": 1024 ** 3, "TB": 1024 ** 4}

    match unit_format:
        case"B": return round(size / units_information["BT"])
        case "BT": return size
        case "KB": return round(size / units_information["KB"])
        case "MB": return round(size / units_information["MB"])
        case "GB": return round(size / units_information["GB"])
        case "TB": return round(size / units_information["TB"])
```

Comment: [typing.Literal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) но может в данном конкретном случае лучше сделать enum?

Comment: Можете продемонстрировать такой пример? 
Я enum никогда не использовал и в предоставленной на сайте документации, не особо вижу смысла его использовать в данном случае.

Comment: А зачем этот огород с `case`  если можно вернуть словарь `return round(size / units_information[unit_format])`?

Comment: Я Python год не использовал и многие упрощения позабыл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с заявки [`PEP 586`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#:%7E:text=as%20generic%20types-,PEP%20586,-%3A%20Literal%20Types) возможно стало использование [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal).

Но по факту это не будет работать как объяснено в абстракции:

> Хотя набор параметров, `Literal[...]` которые могут содержаться во время
> проверки типа, очень мал, фактическая реализация `typing.Literal` не
> будет выполнять никаких проверок во время выполнения.

[Источник в PEP 586](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/#:%7E:text=%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%2C%20Literal%5B...%5D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%2C%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20typing.Literal%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%3A). Доказать данное мы можем на вашем коде далее.

В вашем случае просто можно описать всё условием `not in`. Немного не понимаю какой исходный размер попадает в функцию, похоже на байты, так как вы выводите их как есть. С учётом комментария @Oopss и своих правок исходного массива `units_information`, ввёл некоторые изменения в ваш код. Тут же я оставил на вход литерал `Literal["B"]` На этом же примере можно убедится, что код будет исполняться независимо от того что указано в литерале, а следовательно проверок по литералу не воспроизводится. Код тестировался на `Python 3.10.11`

```
from typing import Literal

def file_size_calc(unit_format: Literal["B"], size: int | float) -> int:
    units_information = {"B": 1/8, "BT": 1, "KB": 1024, "MB": 1024 ** 2, "GB": 1024 ** 3, "TB": 1024 ** 4}
    
    if unit_format not in units_information:
        print('unit_format недопустим')
        raise ValueError('unit_format недопустим')
    
    return round(size/units_information[unit_format])
```

Можем протестировать на файле весом в `1024 кб`

```
print(file_size_calc('B', 1024))
print(file_size_calc('BT', 1024))
print(file_size_calc('KB', 1024))
print(file_size_calc('hello', 1024))
```

Вывод в термнале

```
8192
1024
1
unit_format недопустим
```

В последней строке происходит вывод нашей ошибки типа `ValueError`

```
ValueError: unit_format недопустим
```

А так же подмечаем, что помимо параметра `"B"`, функция приняла и обработала `"BT"` и `"KB"`

---

**А почему?**

А потому что изначально `PEP 586` был акцентирован в первую очередь для подсказок по типам (Type hints), оно же [`PEP 484`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/), цитата оттуда

> Обратите внимание, что этот PEP по-прежнему явно НЕ предотвращает
> другое использование аннотаций, а также не требует (или не запрещает)
> какой-либо конкретной обработки аннотаций, даже если они соответствуют
> этой спецификации. Это просто обеспечивает лучшую координацию, как это
> сделал PEP 333 для веб-платформ.

На самом простейшем примере это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
def get_mult_2(val:int) -> int:
    return val*2

print(get_mult_2('hello'))`
```

Вывод в терминале

```
hellohello
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно заморочится с `pydantic`. Например, как-то так:

```
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError
from typing import Union

class FuncParams(float, Enum):
    B = 1
    BT = 8
    KB =1024
    MB = 1024 ** 2
    GB = 1024 ** 3
    TB = 1024 ** 4

class UnitFormat(BaseModel):
    unit: FuncParams = FuncParams.B
    size: Union[int, float] = 1
    def cnv (self):
        return self.size/self.unit
```

Теперь при

```
print(UnitFormat(unit=8, size=10).cnv()) # unit = 8 - есть в списке параметров
```

получим

> 1.25

а при

```
print(UnitFormat(unit=4, size=10).cnv()) # unit = 4 - нет в списке параметров
```

получим ошибку валидации с подсказкой по типам принимаемых данных

Comment: По-моему оверкилл (особенно с учётом того, что pydantic тащит с собой нативную либу на несколько мегабайт...)